# Review action should happen within the context of the queue the item is accessed from

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review, late-answers

Some items can show up in multiple review queues. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/779812) in particular showed up in the Late Answers review queue.

At the time it also had a suggested edit pending against it. I hit the `edit` link, at which point I was forwarded to the same question *but in the Suggested Edits queue*. I approved the edit, then nothing further happened. I then refreshed the Late Answers queue, and found the same question still there, but now showing one approval (mine) for the edit.

If I select to edit a late answer, and there are no current pending edit approvals then editing the post will be done inline and cause the `I'm Done` button to light up. However if there are edit approvals required, it is executed within the context of the Suggested Edits queue, I am no longer within the Late Answers queue, and the action I took doesn't count within the Late Answers queue.