# Reviewing a suggested edit should count as an action in the First Posts/Late Answers review queues

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, late-answers

When reviewing First Posts or Late Answers, one of the options offered by the UI is to review a pending suggested edit on the post; the 'edit (1)' link invites you to do so. However, after returning to the review, this action doesn't 'count'; the 'No Action' button is still activated, instead of the 'I'm Done' button.

Just like editing a post, or even *suggesting* an edit, this shouldn't count as No Action.

[image]

Comment: Outside of the review queue the edit link opens in a dialog. This would probably be necessary in the queue too in order to implement this request.

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149929/review-action-should-happen-within-the-context-of-the-queue-the-item-is-accessed?rq=1

Comment: I'd argue that only Approve/Improve/Reject and Edit should count but not Reject as you're not taking action on the post but rather the SE then instead. But this is a nice suggestion and it would be nice if it opened inline too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reviewing a suggested edit from a review queue jumps to the suggested edit queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/reviewing-a-suggested-edit-from-a-review-queue-jumps-to-the-suggested-edit-queue)

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog no, not really. My main point is that the action should count as an action in the current queue; I understand that it's hard for the review UI to redirect me back to the FP/LA queues.