# "I'm Done" for Late Answers after "approve edit"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, edits

Sometimes when I feel that a "late answer" needs editing, there's already a suggested edit over there. But approving it (of course after inspection) doesn't enable the "I'm Done" action. On top of that, it switches me to "Review Suggested Edits".

Though I come back to that page, even refreshing it doesn't work.

Shouldn't this be changed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reviewing a suggested edit should count as an action in the First Posts/Late Answers review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327140/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel Kinda similar, but here there's another problem of switching to "Review Suggested Edits".

Comment: Yeah, that happens in my animation too. I just didn't mention it, since it looked rather normal to me (I guess; it's been a while).

Comment: @Glorfindel It doesn't look normal me to me because when I'm reviewing late answers, it's annoying to get my attention diverted to suggested edits. Anyways, I had put the discussion tag.

Comment: Well, you do make a deliberate choice to review something else than late answers (or first posts). But I would certainly not mind if it would return to the original queue, no.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yah that's why I'm requesting a feature to automatically return to my original review.

Comment: Sure (BTW, I handcrafted the first comment, I didn't vote to close. I was just triggered by *But approving it (of course after inspection) doesn't enable the "I'm Done" action.*)

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Now that deals with the second part only. Which of the two flags should close my question on this *theme*?

Comment: That's the advantage of duplicates: we can close a question as a duplicate of *both* of them.

Comment: @Glorfindel Lol that's new to me and I agree with this decision. But I am disappointed by your *"BTW, I handcrafted the first comment"*.

Comment: You might not realize, but if I had voted to close it, it would be dupehammered, and I wasn't entirely sure it was what you meant. That's why I handcrafted the comment ... And I felt obliged to point it out since you don't have the reputation (yet) to view close votes on your own question.

Comment: @Glorfindel It was a bad day on SE network today: unfair review ban, peer pressure,... It might be the reason I overlooked that, I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem, I understand :)