# Can we have suggested edits reviews be a pop-up while reviewing another queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing the *Late Answers* queue (this might apply to other queues, I encountered it with this one) we might want to edit the answer. If we do, the edit window will be inside the scope of the review and when posting the edit, we will be back to the review page, being able to select "I'm Done".

But if there is already a proposed edit that we want to review, we will be redirected to review it inside the *Suggested Edits* queue. This means that when we submit the review, we will keep getting more edit items to review, ***instead of going back to the original Late Answers queue*** item. This deprives us from marking the approval/rejection of the edit as the action taken on the late answer (i.e. approving an edit should be equal to editing as an action taken on the late answer).

I would like to suggest changing the edit review from a different queue to be a pop-up, similar to reviewing an edit from the question's page itself and not from the *Suggested Edits* queue.

Comment: I encountered the same problem a while ago: [Reviewing a suggested edit should count as an action in the First Posts/Late Answers review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327140/295232). Also related: [Reviewing a suggested edit from a review queue jumps to the suggested edit queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148004/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks I really did try to look for duplicates as I had the feeling it must have come up at some moment by someone else - but didn't find those. Should this be a duplicate then?

Comment: No problem. My question doesn't mention the popup, but Gilles' does, so I believe it's a duplicate, yes.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes Gilles' one is quite similar, only problem is that it's from 8 years ago with 70 views... :(

Comment: @Tomerikoo Maybe edit that post to provide more information. Hopefully, it gets considered now.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes I was considering this. Thanks for confirming that's the right course of action. I just did, but I can only suggest... Hopefully it will get some renewed attention